# Admin Category Product count shows wrong value when Is Anchor is yes

Tags: magento-1.7, category

I was having an issue of product count in the admin, I used the following query

```
DELETE FROM catalog_category_product where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM (catalog_product_entity))
```

Now at least I can see the correct count but as soon I change the **Is Anchor** to Yes, it shows wrong count again. why is that?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @Marius, added screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah. This is an old debate.
This is actually a feature not a bug.
Once you set a category to be `anchor` the product count for that category is determined by the products in that category and all its child categories.
For a technical view, take a look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection::loadProductCount`. Specially in the `if ($countAnchor) {` section.
It does exactly what I described above.

Comment: ok, let me confirm by counting the child and its own products.

Comment: @marius: is there a way to undo this behaviour. As earlier my client didn't wanted this behaviour. I had to convince him to go with it...

Comment: @MTM. You can try making the 3rd parameter of the method `loadProductCount` default to `false` instead of `true` but I don't know the implications for the rest of the application.

Comment: The site is live, I can't take chances, better convince the client like Dexter :)

Comment: @Marius: what do you think is suppose to be the logic behind this implementation?

Comment: When viewing a category page, if it's set as anchor you see the products from the child categories also. That's the only logic I think.

Comment: In my opinion it's kind of buggy as it doesn't take into account which scope is selected and if a product is assigned to the category in that particular website.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior of Magento for displaying products when category are Anchored. I don't know the exact logic behind it but, this is what i have observed.

1) Suppose you have a Main category `Office Chairs` in your case. Now this category may be having three subcatgory `ie: Rolling chair, Steel Chairs and Wooden chair`

2) Suppose you have inserted 10 products in each of subcategories and 5 in Main category ie: `Office Chairs`

3) Now when the category is not Anchored ie: Is `Anchor -> NO`, The category `Office Chairs` will only show the 5 products associated with it.

4) When you make this category Anchored ie: `Is Anchor -> YES` It will show the products of the Main Cateory ie `Office Chairs` and also the products of its child category ie 'Rolling, steel and wooden chairs'. This is how Magento behaves.

Conclusion: The Anchored Category will display all the products ie: Products associated with Main category and also the products associated to its children category.

I don't know the exact reason for implementing it in the manner it is at present. Hope others at forum can provide light on it.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and just tested this. Without any issue, it works perfectly.

```
DELETE FROM catalog_category_product
where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM (catalog_product_entity))
```