# Magento : Categories Page Products Count Showing Wrong in Admin

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, category

I have totally added **1594** products in my Magento store. Here **806** products are `enabled` other **788** products are `disabled`.

In `catalog->manage categories` counting product shows wrongly see below image.

[image]

I have a `Categorie` called **WHAT'S NEW** it showing **817** products.
And `Sub Categorie` are

1. Bollywood Stars **(99)**
2. Fun & Funky **(132)**
3. Floral Rhapsody **(51)**
4. Charming Delights **(98)**

Here please count the `sub categories` totally **380**. But in parent categories shows **817**. How it comes...?

And I refer these links [Link Here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29573/admin-category-product-count-shows-wrong-value-when-is-achor-is-yes) if I select `Is Anchor` **no** in view page `PRICE`, `COLOR` are hidden.

So how can I solve this counting problem..?

Comment: Are you sure there are no products assigned to "Whats New" category specifically?

Comment: @John: There are **672** products assigned  in `Whats New` category. And thanks for your replay

Comment: @RameshS Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @zus: No i was re-install.

Answer (score 3):

Please use reindex in Magento from the Admin Panel or from the command line.

**Method 1: Using the Admin Panel**

1. Log in to Magento Admin Panel.
2. Click System > Index Management
3. On the left, select all categories to reindex.
4. From the Actions drop-down list, select Reindex Data and then click Submit

**Method 2: Using the command line**

1. Go to your navigate to the shell directory:

cd shell

2. Reindex of all categories

php indexer.php --reindexall

Comment: Thank You @Vadym Kalin i tried this but not working

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue and just tested this. Without any issue, it works perfectly.

```
DELETE FROM catalog_category_product
where product_id NOT IN (SELECT entity_id FROM (catalog_product_entity))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, am up vote your answer because it is usefull

Comment: it returns zero rows, still there are many categories with big difference

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/122854/57027)
Category children count fix

https://gist.github.com/frosit/288bbb263b55c4dc8796fc79aeeb86df

Comment: Great thanks for your answer Alex, actually  am installed new one. Now it working fine.

Comment: Any way am up vote your answer